# How to emit a custom Event from a custom Class and listen to it in Dojo 1.11?

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, event-handling

I'm trying to create a Custom Dojo Class, which emits a custom event, and I'm trying to listen to that event from the calling class.

I haven't found a signle complete sample for this, and I'm stuck here.

I've tried the following:

In my custom class, I have the following code:

```
   on.emit(this, "PointFound", {
           Msg:"Found a point Within minDistance",
           point:selctedPoint
           });
```

This does not cause any error. Where I'm stuck is in how to listen to it.

When I try (after properly initializing the class):

```
            on(findUtilInstance,"PointFound", function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });
```

I get an error message: `Error: Target must be an event emitter`

When I try (after properly initializing the class):

```
            findUtilInstance.on("PointFound", function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });
```

I get the error: `TypeError: findUtilInstance.on is not a function`

What is the correct way in Dojo 1.11.2 to fire custom events, and receive them?

Comment: Have you consider using dojo/topic instead?

Comment: @GibboK I'm not familiar with dojo/topic, but I will be having multiple instances of this custom class; Can I subscribe to the events on the different instances & differentiate between them using topic?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I can high suggest to evaluate this pattern as has several benefits.

Answer (score 2):

`dojo/on` it's only for DOM nodes and it works if you extend from `dijit/_WidgetBase`, then there's a method called on() which you can use, for example:

```
myWidget.on("customevent", function(data) {
    console.log( " received notification "+data );
});
```

If instead your extend from `dojo/_base/declare` you could consider using `dojo/topic` and implement Publish–subscribe pattern.
Which allow "classes/modules" to communicate each other.

> dojo/topic provides a centralized hub for publishing and subscribing
>   to global messages by topic. Topics can be subscribed to by using
>   topic.subscribe(), and messages can publish by using topic.publish().

Basically you can use `dojo/topic` for:

- Broadcast (publish) messages (event/topic) to one or multiple instances of your classes.
- From each instance your could listen (subscribe) to your message and apply your logic there.

---

```
require(["dojo/topic"], function(topic){
    topic.subscribe("some/topic", function(){
        console.log("received:", arguments);
    });
    // ...
    topic.publish("some/topic", "one", "two");
});
```